# Overloading ostream operator with a vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've created a class that has a vector of messages and I need to overload the ostream operator so it outputs the index and each message on a new line. I have seen tons of examples that output only one predetermined line, but the problem is I don't know how big my vector is.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
my_message.messages = {"line 1", "line 2", "line 3"};
cout<<my_message<<endl;
```

Output:

```
Message Contents:
01: Line 1
02: Line 2
03: Line 3
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], what is `my_message`? And also, write down what you have already tried and how it is failing

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` has a method named `size()` which can return the size of this vector.So we can write like this:

```
class my_message
{
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, my_message &c);
    public:
        my_message(std::vector<std::string> v) :messages(v) {}
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> messages;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, my_message &c)
{
    for(std::size_t index = 0; index < c.messages.size(); ++index)
        os << index <<": " << c.messages[index] << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

If `my_message.messages` is private, `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, my_message)` should be a friend member of `my_message`.

Answer (score -1):

Overload `operator <<` to for the `class MY_MESSAGES` like below.
Then inside the overloaded operator function just iterate over the messages `vector` and print the individual message.

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& o, class MY_MESSAGES my_message)
{
    int size = my_message.messages.size();

    o << Message Contents: << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0;i < size; i++)
    {
        o <<  i+1 << my_message.messages[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return o;
}
```